# Visual Studio Code creates new lines on its own while coding in python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, code-formatting

Visual Studio Code creates new lines on its own while using Python, I have no idea how to get rid of it, and it drives me mad.

Example:

```py
ap.add_argument("-p", "--path", help="path",
                default="C:\Data\file.txt")
```

I want this to be in one line, it's not exactly long, but Visual Studio Code knows better and just won't let me. It goes back to two lines after saving the file.

Comment: Does it add line breaks while typing, or only when saving, or both?

Comment: Do you have [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=KevinRose.vsc-python-indent) extension installed? It's also probably word-wrapping. You can turn it off in your settings. To go to settings use `Cmd + ,` or `Ctrl + ,`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your visual studio has a syntax for python and it uses its syntax to auto save python file into the proper format.

[image]

First go to settings and preferences and change the auto save format and not wanting it to be like that
(Preferences->Settings->User).

Then make use of word wrap (View->Word Wrap).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nothing changed. I guess I will just use notepad++ for now.

Comment: try turning or uninstalling your python extensions if you had one, i'd highly recommend that

Comment: solved, for some reason settings didn't save, I had to fix some glitch in configuration file manually. Not the best first impression of VSCode. No need to enable Word Wrap too by the way.